# Identifying an anime with Joan of Arc fighting guy who pulls swords out of wall

Tags: story-identification, anime

This anime I remember a scene where two normal people can summon a warrior from ancient times and during a battle some girl summons Joan of Arc and some guy summons a character who's ability is to use any sword ever created mythical or real and he fights Joan with the Excalibur

Comment: Probably Fate/stay night or Fate/Apocrypha.

Comment: In the spirit of https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11552/, I've migrated this identification request, which appears to be about a fantasy anime, over from [anime.se]

Comment: In case you ever decide to join us here, knowing when you watched it would help, as well as a few more plot details. You can find more help for adding plot details in [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872)

Comment: The Fate/Stay series is great and also on Netflix (Canada).  Highly recommend.  Unlimited Blade Works (Night) and Zero are both awesome; Apocrypha is OK but pretty chaotic due to the sheer number of characters, especially if you've never seen either of the other Fate/Stays.  Also, maybe this is just me but I feel like the animation is a little weaker in Apocrypha.

Answer (score 29):

You are probably thinking of **Fate/stay night** (or its prequel, **Fate/Zero**), with a number of details misremembered.

The character who you think is Joan of Arc is actually a genderswapped King Arthur (but until her identity is revealed, people commonly guess that she's Joan of Arc). As such, it is she who uses Excalibur, not her opponents. She is typically called "Saber".

[image: Saber]

There are two characters whose ability could be construed as being able to use any sword ever created. One of them (Gilgamesh) literally owns a copy of every weapon in existence and has the ability to summon them using the so-called "Gate of Babylon". The other (Archer) has the ability to create a copy of (almost) any sword he witnesses.

[image: Gilgamesh]
[image: Archer]

What you recall as "pulling swords out of a wall" is probably the Gate of Babylon, which is really more of a "pulling swords out of thin air" sort of thing, but they all tend to emerge from the same vertical plane, so I can see why you'd recall it being a wall.

[image: Gate of Babylon]

Answer (score 14):

While [Senshin's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175345/20916) ID's both *Fate/Stay Night* and *Fate/Zero* the answer focuses on *Fate/Stay Night* by mentioning Archer and using images of him and Gilgamesh from *Fate/Stay Night*

**I would say however it is actually *Fate/Zero***

First off Senshin is correct in IDing Gilgamesh and Arturia (The Female King Arthur) however there is are 2 parts in the question which don't match the answer being *Fate/Stay Night*

The first thing is

> some girl summons Joan of Arc

Senshin is correct about the mistaken identity of Arturia being Joan of Arc but this was only in Fate/Zero (in *Fate/Stay Night*, to my recollection, Joan of Arc is never mentioned). another person who was summoned, [Gilles de Rais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilles_de_Rais), who fought with Joan in the 100 Year War mistook Arturia for being Joan

[image: Gilles de Rai][image: Jeanne in Fate/Zero]

Also, Arturia wasn't summoned by a girl. she was summon by Kiritsugu who is a man (and is summoned by his son Shirou in *Fate/Stay Night*). however as apart of his plan for fighting in the Holy Grail War Kiritsugu had his wife Irisviel von Einzbern act as if she had summoned Arturia.

[image: Irisviel and Arturia]

The second thing is that while Gilgamesh appears in *Fate/Stay Night*, he was summoned in *Fate/Zero* and survived until his appearance in *Fate/Stay Night* (which takes place several years after *Fate/Zero*).

the person who Gilgamesh follows in *Fate/Stay Night*, Kirei Kotomine wasn't the one who summoned him but it was Kotomine's "Teacher" Tokiomi, but later in *Fate/Zero* Gilgamesh sides with Kotomine

[image: Tokiomi and Gilgamesh][image: Kotomine and Gilgamesh]

Comment: And all that is further complicated by the fact that in _Fate/Apocrypha_ Joan of Arc is actually summoned.

Comment: In Fate/Apocrypha is Joan summoned by a female magician? If so, that may warrant a 3rd answer.

Comment: @KareemElashmawy Nope, Joan is sort of a "special case" in Apocrypha.  She doesn't get summoned by a female magician.

Comment: @KareemElashmawy and to add to what Kalmino said, the second character who can use any sword is Gilgamesh as he brags about having everything ever created (from swords to wine to an ancient airplane) but he doesn't appear in Apocrapha. the only other Fate title with an anime that has both Gilgamesh and "Arturia" is *Fate/Extra* where Nero looks practically the same as Arturia but Joan is not mentioned and the Fate/Extra anime is actually coming out next year which currently does not look to be following the CCC Routes (Fate/Extra CCC is when Gilgamesh appears)